# Android Not Respecting my res folders

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm having some issues in an App that I'm developping in Android:

We are creating an app with support for multiple screens, going from an Samsung Galaxy Ace to a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1, Supporting small, medium, large and x-large screens, but, somehow Android is not respecting my layout-xxxx folders. In Eclipse visual layout editor, when I Change the Screen it moves me to the correct folder, for representing that layout. But, In Android, Emulator or Real Device, the Layouts in their folder aren't displayed the correct way.
My folder structure is like the ones, mentioned at Android Developer:
res/layout-xxxx
res/values-xxxx

I've also read that since Android Honeycomb, somethings changed, the small,large,xlarge qualifiers became depecrated. So We created folders using layout-swdp, and we thought that would be the Solution for Devices with honeycomb +. But, soon we realized that this didn't work.
So, Is there a exact way to do this?. To make Android respect or force, these folders?.
Also, in Android 2.2 when using Dimens, the App didn't start. It tells that there's no dimen 0x01. Thank you In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personaly I would use Screen pixel density (dpi) for each layout.

That is:

```
ldpi: Low-density screens; approximately 120dpi. 
mdpi: Medium-density (on traditional HVGA) screens; approximately 160dpi. 
hdpi: High-density screens; approximately 240dpi. 
xhdpi: Extra high-density screens; approximately 320dpi. 
Added in API Level 8
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: Should I use layout-ldpi, layout-mdpi, ... ?

Comment: @NemesisDoom It should help altought not sure why what you where doing is not working

Comment: Wait a Sec, I'm going to implement what you told me, and see the Result,

Answer (score 0):

The folder should be:

`values` > Standard phone screen

`values-sw600dp` > 7" phone/tablet screen

`values-sw720dp` > 10" tablet

You have to initialize `<dimen name="myvariable"></dimen>` in the XML file within those folders and call inside your XML.

Example:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnHome"
android:layout_width="@dimen/myvariable"
android:layout_height="@dimen/myvariable"
android:text=""
android:background="@drawable/homebutton" />
```

And it will resize based on the screen size.

I am working on my app and that ensures the size is same across all three screen.